# how to unninstall ubuntu but bootmgr is missing and i want to install win xp

Tags: windows-xp

I wanna uninstall ubuntu and install Windows xp. bootmgr is missing, how to fix it?
I have only usb stick with win xp, cd drive broken.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall Ubuntu explicitely, all you need to do is install whatever OS you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Windows XP install on you usb stick, after Windows loads, go into `My computer`. There should be a disk that stands as your partition. Delete that and you should be good. Thats how I've done it in the past.